# Is there a way to pass state values into the Yup validation schema?

Tags: formik, yup

We're using Yup to validate Formik fields. For one field, I need it to be required, or not, depending on the value of a state variable in the parent component; *not* another Formik field.

Roughly what I'd like to do is:

```js
// in the parent component
import validationSchema from './validationSchema.ts'

const MyComponent = () => {
   const [someState, setState] = useState();
   // ...
   <Formik
      validationSchema={validationSchema}
      // ...
}
```

```js
// then, in the validator 

// (find some way to make `someState` available here)

export const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
  myField: Yup.string().test('required', 'Field is required', value => {
     if (someState) {
        return false // field is required if someState is truthy
     } else {
        return true // field is not required if someState is falsey
     }
    //...
```

Does anyone know what the correct approach to this is? I essentially need to be able to **pass state in** to the validation schema when it's invoked.